# Installing OpenLDAP on RHEL 8 -- slapd.pid problem

Tags: openldap

I have compiled the current version of OpenLDAP on a fresh RHEL 8 instance and am setting it up with a signed SSL certificate. When I start slapd, I get `unable to open pid file "/var/run/openldap/slapd.pid": 2 (No such file or directory)`. Surprise, surprise, the openldap directory does not exist.

I created the directory and set ownership to ldap:ldap. Now when I start slapd, I get `Can't open PID file /var/lib/openldap/slapd.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory`. Shouldn't the service be creating the pid file?

I tried troubleshooting by doing `slapd -u ldap -g ldap -d 255` but it doesn't return any errors. It starts up slapd and then hangs indefinitely. Here's the output:

```
632b738b.28af1a7e 0x7fb91fe62840 slapd starting
632b738b.28b084a2 0x7fb918147700 daemon: added 4r listener=(nil)
632b738b.28b0e5e8 0x7fb918147700 daemon: added 7r listener=0x1789270
632b738b.28b11145 0x7fb918147700 daemon: added 8r listener=0x1789360
632b738b.28b2645c 0x7fb918147700 daemon: epoll: listen=7 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
632b738b.28b27b69 0x7fb918147700 daemon: epoll: listen=8 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
632b738b.28b28d61 0x7fb918147700 daemon: activity on 1 descriptor
632b738b.28b2a342 0x7fb918147700 daemon: activity on:632b738b.28b2aaae 0x7fb918147700
632b738b.28b2c02b 0x7fb918147700 daemon: epoll: listen=7 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
632b738b.28b2d2eb 0x7fb918147700 daemon: epoll: listen=8 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
```

Any idea as to what to try next?

Here's my configure if it helps:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc --disable-static --enable-debug --with-tls=openssl --with-cyrus-sasl --enable-dynamic --enable-crypt --enable-spasswd --enable-slapd --enable-modules --enable-rlookups --enable-backends=mod --disable-ndb --disable-sql --disable-shell --disable-bdb --disable-hdb --enable-overlays=mod
```

slapd.service

```
[Unit]
Description=OpenLDAP Server Daemon
After=syslog.target network-online.target
Documentation=man:slapd
Documentation=man:slapd-mdb

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/var/lib/openldap/slapd.pid
Environment="SLAPD_URLS=ldap:/// ldapi:/// ldaps:///"
Environment="SLAPD_OPTIONS=-F /etc/openldap/slapd.d"
ExecStart=/usr/libexec/slapd -u ldap -g ldap -h ${SLAPD_URLS} $SLAPD_OPTIONS

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: It looks like you have two things looking for the pid file in different places. Are you running slapd under the control of systemd? What does the unit file look like? I generally just remove `pidfile` from my slapd configuration because it's unnecessary, but if you have something other than slapd looking for it you would need to address that as well.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you're referring to when you say systemd or unit file. Can you guide me there? I tried commenting out the olcPidFile line and doing a grep across the `/etc/openldap` directories to make sure there were no longer any pid references. I get the same `/var/lib/openldap` error.

Comment: Taking a step back: How are you starting slapd?

Comment: `systemctl start slapd`

Comment: Okay. So, `systemctl` is a command that interacts with `systemd` to start/stop services. This behavior is controlled by "unit files"; somewhere on your system you have a file called `slapd.service`, possibly installed in `/etc/systemd/system` or in `/usr/lib/systemd/system`. It would help if you could add the content of that file to your question.

Comment: Ah ha! There's that pid path. Should I just remove it or do something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first error is:

```
unable to open pid file "/var/run/openldap/slapd.pid": 2 (No such file or directory)
```

There are a couple of ways to resolve this error.

### Fix the filesystem

`slapd` is trying to write a pid file to `/var/run/openldap/slapd.pid`, but the directory `/var/run/openldap` doesn't exist. `/var/run` is a symlink to `/run`, which is an ephemeral directory: it is re-created every time the system boots.

To create a directory in `/run`, you can use `systemd-tmpfiles`. In `/etc/tmpfiles.d`, create a file `slapd.conf` with the following content:

```
D /run/openldap 0755 ldap ldap
```

Then run:

```
systemd-tmpfiles --create
```

This will ensure that `/var/run/openldap` exists and that it gets created when the system boots.

You will need to update your slapd systemd unit to use the correct path:

```
[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/var/run/openldap/slapd.pid
Environment="SLAPD_URLS=ldap:/// ldapi:/// ldaps:///"
Environment="SLAPD_OPTIONS=-F /etc/openldap/slapd.d"
ExecStart=/usr/libexec/slapd -u ldap -g ldap -h ${SLAPD_URLS} $SLAPD_OPTIONS
```

### Remove PidFile from your configuration

Your slapd unit file is using the `PIDFile` directive because you're running `slapd` as `Type=forking`. From the `systemd.service(5) man page:

> `PIDFile=`
>
> Takes a path referring to the PID file of the service. Usage of this option is recommended for services where `Type=` is set to forking. The path specified typically points to a file below `/run/`. If a relative path is specified it is hence prefixed with `/run/`. The service manager will read the PID of the main process of the service from this file after start-up of the service.

So if we don't need to use `Type=forking`, we can remove the PIDFile configuration here and the corresponding `PidFile` configuration in slapd. We modify the `slapd` command line to include `-d0`, which causes `slapd` to run in the foreground:

```
[Service]
Type=simple
Environment="SLAPD_URLS=ldap:/// ldapi:/// ldaps:///"
Environment="SLAPD_OPTIONS=-F /etc/openldap/slapd.d"
ExecStart=/usr/libexec/slapd -d0 -u ldap -g ldap -h ${SLAPD_URLS} $SLAPD_OPTIONS
```

And then remove your `PidFile` setting from `slapd.conf` (or the `olcPidFile` setting from `cn=config`).

Comment: I tried both of your suggested solutions and still was getting `Can't open PID file /var/run/openldap/slapd.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory`. I did a grep across the entire drive and found the pid file path in `/etc/openldap/slapd.conf`. I commented that out and now slapd starts correctly. Thanks for walking me through this!